# How can I edit a Tumblr .gif on my Android phone?

Tags: android, image-editor

Any tools to do this?  I want to crop out part of a .gif and save the new edited version in .gif format. When I edit using regular editing tools, the .gif turns into a regular photograph.

Answer (score 1):

There are many GIF editors for Android. I have tried these and they both do the job:

- Kayak Studio [GIF maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kayak.studio.gifmaker&hl=en)
- g(x)labs [Gif mini](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gxapplab.minigif&hl=en)

They both are pretty straightforward, just open the app, locate the GIF and they give you some options, including crop. You can enter "crop gif" in play store and it will give you dozens of different apps, if you aren't happy with those. GIF is trendy now and there are many very similar apps.

Or you can use https://ezgif.com/crop if you don't mind using online tools, it should work fine on touchscreen.